# Getting an image from an IP camera

Tags: ip

I'm looking at [this camera](http://www.hikvision.com/europe/products_show.asp?id=9638) in order to take static pictures. [This site](https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Hikvision) showed me that it its probably possible, but the documentation for the camera doesn't seem to mention this ability. I'm planning on writing my own software to take the pictures because it will be part of another service. Is it normal that IP cameras work like this? And should I be looking for a specific specification\feature, in general, that would open up an channel for static, one-time pictures from a IP cam?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: usually, look for ONVIF feature, there are many software that can capture images